# Android retrofit : i want to update or refresh data every day at specific time or once a day, retrieved data successfully Nd works offline locally too

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, android-service, android-room

I want to update those data or refresh data every day but at a specific time of the day or once a day I can say that,

how can I achieve this?

which method should I follow here's the code

fragment activity

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
            );

    activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    apiCallInterface = ApiService.createService(ApiCallInterface.class);

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    datumList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.retroRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    fetchFromDb();        
}

private void fetchFromDb() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String array = sharedPreferences.getString("category", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Datum>>() {
    }.getType();
    datumList = gson.fromJson(array, type);
    if (datumList != null) {
        retrofitAdapter = new RetrofitAdapter(getContext(), datumList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(retrofitAdapter);
    } else {
        if (activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            fetchFromServer();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

    private void fetchFromServer() {
    Call<MenuResponse> call = apiCallInterface
            .getResponseData(data);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MenuResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MenuResponse> call, Response<MenuResponse> response) {
            datumList = (ArrayList<Datum>) response.body().getData();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("category", gson.toJson(datumList));
            editor.apply();
            retrofitAdapter = new RetrofitAdapter(getContext(), datumList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(retrofitAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MenuResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure something went wrong" + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

these two methods I used to temporary first I used room DB bt for temp. the task I tried shared preferences now I want to achieve refresh or update data task by updating data once a day or at a specific time on the day

Answer (score 0):

You can use WorkManager for these kind of stuff.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) you can find more information about it.

Just be aware that on some devices like Xiaomi, your task may never get to trigger if the app is in the background (not running).
But WorkManager is the most reliable at the moment. It probably do the task with some delay, but at least your task gets done (still talking about custom OS devices).
In other devices(stock android) you can use both WorkManager and AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

this works totally fine!!

```
public void runOnceADay() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);

    int lastDay = sharedPreferences.getInt("day", 0);

    if (lastDay != currentDay) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("day", currentDay);
        editor.commit();
        //perform task ...
        Log.d("day", "updated!");
        fetchFromServer();

    } else {
        Log.d("day", "task will be performed tomorrow!");
        fetchFromDb();
    }

}
```

Comment: This will work but not when app is in the background, I think the OP wants this to run in the background so Workmanager is his best solution.